# How do I know if piwik GeoIP is working or not?

Tags: matomo

I installed GeoIP PECL and copied the latest GeoLite City database to misc/GeoIPCity.dat. Now the admin page says
"According to this provider, your current location is: Hayward, CA United States". However, all visits are still shown as 'Unknown' in Visitors/Locations & Provider page.
How can I find out what I missed? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I need to add this line to my php.ini:

```
[geoip]


geoip.custom_directory = /home/deployer/piwik/misc/
```